# How to update source property "attribution" in Mapbox GL?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl

I am using mapbox gl library. First layer is getting added then under that layer source is getting added. like below shown :

```
sourceObj = {
      type: 'raster',
      tiles: tileUrls,
      attribution : "Copyright"
      scheme,
      style,
      styles,
    };
map.addSource(`${this.asset.uuid}-data`, source);
const layer = {
        id: `${this.asset.uuid}-label`,
        type: 'raster',
        source: `${this.asset.uuid}-data`,
        minzoom: 0,
        maxzoom: 22,
      };
      map.addLayer(layer, this.asset.uuid);
```

We are loading bing tiles under `tileUrl`. Tiles are working fine.
Now I have to update this attribution based on zoom level. Am using map zoom start and end event to update but how to update not getting.
`setData` only work with type `Point` and `GeoJson` not with `Raster` or `vector`.
I tried all documentation of mapbox but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After so many tried found this hacky solution. Using https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/markers/#attributioncontrol property.

```
source.attribution = 'Text to be update';
map._controls[0]._updateAttributions(); //
```

This can be iterate through _controls and get right customAttribution instance. I have use hack way.